# Parse nested Json of different nested patterns retrieve and compare attributes with excel row elements

Tags: python, json, pandas, parsing

Working with a JSON file that has nested structures and I want to extract attributes from the last level of the nested structure. Additionally, I want to compare these attributes with elements in an Excel row. Once we have the attributes, we can compare them with the Excel row elements.
Excel data:

[image]

Here are some patterns from my json file:
Service1:

```
"_comment": "Dict { Dict { list of Dicts [{ --> Value type = List or Integer",

"Services": {
    "RoadAttributes": {
      "egoInformationCompex": [
        {
          "speedlimit": {
            "id": 5,
            "distanceStdDev": 5,
            "value": 5,
            "indexAdditionalSignList": [
              5,
              5,
              5
            ],
            "source": 5,
            "unit": 1
          },
          "trafficOnline": {
            "id": 5,
            "distanceStdDev": 5,
            "value": 5,
            "indexAdditionalSignList": [
              5,
              5,
              5
            ],
            "source": 5,
            "unit": 1
          },
          "averageSpeed": {
            "id": 5,
            "distanceStdDev": 5,
            "value": 5,
            "indexAdditionalSignList": [
              5,
              5,
              5
            ],
            "source": 5,
            "unit": 1
          },
          "slope": {
            "slope": 1.0,
            "distance": 5
          },
          "messageCounter": 4
        }
      ]
    }
  },
```

Service2:

```
"_comment": "Dict { Dict { list of list of Dicts [{ --> Value type = List or Integer or Dict",
 "Services": {
    "RoadAttributesExtended": {
      "onlineInformation": [
        {
          "localHazardList": [
            {
              "id": 5,
              "distance": 5,
              "trafficIncidentID": 5,
              "combinedEventCode": 5,
              "localHazardType": 2
            }
          ],
          "trafficOnlineList": [
            {
              "id": 5,
              "distance": 5,
              "distanceStdDev": 5,
              "value": {
                "value1": 5,
                "value2": 5
              },
              "indexAdditionalSignList": [
                5,
                5,
                5
              ],
              "source": 5,
              "relevance": 5,
              "unit": 1
            }
          ],
          "speedCourseListA": [
            {
              "id": 5,
              "distance": 5,
              "distanceStdDev": 5,
              "speed": 5,
              "isGapStart": true,
              "confidence": 5
            }
          ],
          "speedCourseListABucketType": 5,
          "speedCourseListAStatisticsType": 5,
          "speedCourseListB": [
            {
              "id": 5,
              "distance": 5,
              "distanceStdDev": 5,
              "speed": 5,
              "isGapStart": true,
              "confidence": 5
            }
          ],
          "speedCourseListBBucketType": 5,
          "speedCourseListBStatisticsType": 5,
          "acaEnableHandsFree": [
            {
              "id": 5,
              "distance": 5,
              "value1": 5,
              "source": 5
            }
          ],
          "roadObstacleList": [
            {
              "id": 5,
              "distance": 5,
              "roadObstacleType": 5,
              "height": 5,
              "length": 5,
              "roadObstaclePosition": 5,
              "lane": 5,
              "crossingProbability": 5,
              "source": 5
            }
          ],
          "roadCategoryList": [
            {
              "id": 5,
              "distance": 5,
              "value": {
                "value1": 5,
                "value2": 5
              },
              "source": 5
            }
          ],
          "roadWavinessList": [
            {
              "id": 5,
              "distance": 5,
              "value": {
                "value1": 5,
                "value2": 5
              },
              "source": 5
            }
          ],
          "messageCounter": 4
        }
      ]
    }
  },
```

Here is python code I tried:

```
with open(r"ampmin.json") as f:
    data = js.load(f)
    for d in data:
        Temp_Data = d['Services']
        if len (Temp_Data)!= 0:
            for s1_key, s1_val in Temp_Data.items():
                    # print(s1_key, type(s1_val))
                    for s2_key, s2_val in s1_val.items():
                        #print(s2_key, type(s2_val))
                        for s3_items in s2_val:
                            #print('[0]', type(s3_items))
                            for s4_key, s4_val in s3_items.items():
                                print(s4_val)
```

Comment: There's no need for the `if` statement. If the length is 0, the loop will end immediately.

Answer (score 0):

This code should help you:

```
import operator
from functools import reduce
from typing import Any, Generator, Union
from collections import defaultdict
from random import randrange
from random import choice

nested_dict = lambda: defaultdict(nested_dict)


class Tuppsub(tuple):
    """Protects tuples internally from being flattened, same as ProtectedTuple"""

    pass


class ProtectedTuple(tuple):
    """Protects tuples from being flattened, same as Tuppsub"""

    pass


class ProtectedList(list):
    """Protects lists from being flattened"""

    pass


class ProtectedDict(dict):
    """Protects dicts from being flattened"""

    pass


class ProtectedSet(set):
    """Protects sets from being flattened"""

    pass


def aa_flatten_dict_tu(
        v: dict,
        listitem: tuple,
        forbidden: tuple = (list, tuple, set, frozenset),
        allowed: tuple = (
                str,
                int,
                float,
                complex,
                bool,
                bytes,
                type(None),
                ProtectedTuple,
                ProtectedList,
                ProtectedDict,
                ProtectedSet,
                Tuppsub,
        ),
) -> Generator:

    if (
            isinstance(v, dict)
            or (hasattr(v, "items") and hasattr(v, "keys"))
            and not isinstance(v, allowed)
    ):  # we check right away if it is a dict or something similar (with keys/items). If we miss something, we will
        # only get the keys back.
        for k, v2 in v.items():
            newtu = listitem + (k,)  # we accumulate all keys in a tuple
            if isinstance(v2, allowed):
                yield Tuppsub((v2, newtu))
            # and check if there are more dicts (nested) in this dict
            else:
                yield from aa_flatten_dict_tu(
                    v2, listitem=newtu, forbidden=forbidden, allowed=allowed
                )
    elif isinstance(v, forbidden) and not isinstance(
            v, allowed
    ):  # if we have an iterable without keys (list, tuple, set, frozenset) we have to enumerate them to be able to
        # access the original dict values later: di['blabla'][0] instead of di['blabla']

        for indi, v2 in enumerate(v):

            if isinstance(v2, allowed):
                yield Tuppsub((v2, (listitem + (indi,))))
            #  if the value is not in our allowed data types, we have to check if it is an iterable
            else:
                yield from aa_flatten_dict_tu(
                    v2,
                    listitem=(listitem + (indi,)),
                    forbidden=forbidden,
                    allowed=allowed,
                )
    elif isinstance(v, allowed):
        #  if the datatype is allowed, we yield it
        yield Tuppsub((v, listitem))

    # Brute force to check if we have an iterable. We have to get all iterables!
    else:
        try:
            for indi2, v2 in enumerate(v):

                try:
                    if isinstance(v2, allowed):
                        yield Tuppsub((v2, (listitem + (indi2,))))

                    else:
                        yield aa_flatten_dict_tu(
                            v2,
                            listitem=(listitem + (indi2,)),
                            forbidden=forbidden,
                            allowed=allowed,
                        )
                except Exception:
                    # if there is an exception, it is probably not an iterable, so we yield it
                    yield Tuppsub((v2, listitem))
        except Exception:
            # if there is an exception, it is probably not an iterable, so we yield it
            yield Tuppsub((v, listitem))


def fla_tu(
        item: Any,
        walkthrough:
        tuple = (),  # accumulate nested keys / don't pass anything here unless you know what you are doing
        forbidden: tuple = (
                list,
                tuple,
                set,
                frozenset,
        ),  # forbidden to yield, need to be flattened
        allowed: tuple = (  # Data types we don't want to touch!
                str,
                int,
                float,
                complex,
                bool,
                bytes,
                type(None),
                ProtectedTuple,  #
                ProtectedList,
                ProtectedDict,
                ProtectedSet,
                Tuppsub  # This is the secret - Inherit from tuple and exclude it from being flattened -
                # ProtectedTuple does the same thing
        ),
        dict_variation=(
        # we don't check with isinstance(), rather with type(), that way we don't have to import collections.
                "collections.defaultdict",
                "collections.UserDict",
                "collections.OrderedDict",
        ),
) -> Generator:
    """
    Use this function to flatten any iterable
    """
    if isinstance(item, allowed):  # allowed items, so let's yield them
        yield Tuppsub((item, (walkthrough,)))
    elif isinstance(item, forbidden) and not isinstance(item, allowed):
        for ini, xaa in enumerate(item):
            if not isinstance(xaa, allowed):
                try:
                    yield from fla_tu(
                        xaa,
                        walkthrough=(walkthrough + (ini,)),
                        forbidden=forbidden,
                        allowed=allowed,
                        dict_variation=dict_variation,
                    )  # if we have an iterable, we check recursively for other iterables

                except Exception:

                    yield Tuppsub(
                        (xaa, (walkthrough + (ini,)))
                    )  # we just yield the value (value, (key1,key2,...))  because it is probably not an iterable
            else:
                yield Tuppsub((xaa, (walkthrough + (ini,))))
    elif isinstance(
            item, dict
    ):  # we need to pass dicts to aa_flatten_dict_tu(), they need a special treatment, if not, we only get the keys from the dict back
        if not isinstance(item, allowed):
            yield from aa_flatten_dict_tu(
                item, listitem=walkthrough, forbidden=forbidden, allowed=allowed
            )
        else:
            yield Tuppsub((item, (walkthrough,)))
            # let's try to catch all different dict variations by using ( hasattr(item, "items") and hasattr(item, "keys").
    # If we dont pass it to aa_flatten_dict_tu(), we only get the keys back.
    #
    # -> (hasattr(item, "items") and hasattr(item, "keys") -> Maybe better here:     elif isinstance( item, dict ):
    elif (str(type(item)) in dict_variation) or (
            hasattr(item, "items") and hasattr(item, "keys")
    ):
        if not isinstance(item, allowed):
            yield from aa_flatten_dict_tu(
                dict(item), listitem=walkthrough, forbidden=forbidden, allowed=allowed
            )
        else:
            yield Tuppsub((item, (walkthrough,)))
    # isinstance(item, pd.DataFrame) maybe better?
    elif "DataFrame" in str(type(item)):

        yield from aa_flatten_dict_tu(
            item.to_dict(),
            # pandas needs to be converted to dict first, if not, we only get the columns back. Copying might not be necessary
            listitem=walkthrough,
            forbidden=forbidden,
            allowed=allowed,

        )

    # # many iterables are hard to identify using isinstance() / type(), so we have to use brute force to check if it is
    # an iterable. If one iterable escapes, we are screwed!
    else:
        try:
            for ini2, xaa in enumerate(item):
                try:
                    if isinstance(xaa, allowed):  # yield only for allowed data types

                        yield Tuppsub(
                            (xaa, (walkthrough + (ini2,)))
                        )  # yields (value, (key1,key2,...)) -> always same format -> first value, then all keys in another tuple
                    else:  # if it is not in the allowed data types, we check recursively for other iterables
                        yield from fla_tu(
                            xaa,
                            walkthrough=(
                                (walkthrough + (ini2,))
                            ),  # yields (value, (key1,key2,...))
                            forbidden=forbidden,
                            allowed=allowed,
                            dict_variation=dict_variation,
                        )
                except Exception:

                    yield Tuppsub(
                        (xaa, (walkthrough + (ini2,)))
                    )  # in case of an exception, we yield  (value, (key1,key2,...))
        except Exception:

            yield Tuppsub(
                (item, (walkthrough,))
            )  # in case of an exception, we yield  (value, (key1,key2,...))

data={"Services": {
    "RoadAttributes": {
      "egoInformationCompex": [
        {
          "speedlimit": {
            "id": 5,
            "distanceStdDev": 5,
            "value": 5,
            "indexAdditionalSignList": [
              5,
              5,
              5
            ],
            "source": 5,
            "unit": 1
          },
          "trafficOnline": {
            "id": 5,
            "distanceStdDev": 5,
            "value": 5,
            "indexAdditionalSignList": [
              5,
              5,
              5
            ],
            "source": 5,
            "unit": 1
          },
          "averageSpeed": {
            "id": 5,
            "distanceStdDev": 5,
            "value": 5,
            "indexAdditionalSignList": [
              5,
              5,
              5
            ],
            "source": 5,
            "unit": 1
          },
          "slope": {
            "slope": 1.0,
            "distance": 5
          },
          "messageCounter": 4
        }
      ]
    }
  }}
list(fla_tu(data))
# output - now easy to work with:

    [(5,
  ('Services',
   'RoadAttributes',
   'egoInformationCompex',
   0,
   'speedlimit',
   'id')),
 (5,
  ('Services',
   'RoadAttributes',
   'egoInformationCompex',
   0,
   'speedlimit',
   'distanceStdDev')),
 (5,
  ('Services',
   'RoadAttributes',
   'egoInformationCompex',
   0,
   'speedlimit',
   'value')),
 (5,
  ('Services',
   'RoadAttributes',
   'egoInformationCompex',
   0,
   'speedlimit',
   'indexAdditionalSignList',
   0)),
 (5,
  ('Services',
   'RoadAttributes',
   'egoInformationCompex',
   0,
   'speedlimit',
   'indexAdditionalSignList',
   1)),
 (5,
  ('Services',
   'RoadAttributes',
   'egoInformationCompex',
   0,
   'speedlimit',
   'indexAdditionalSignList',
   2)),
 (5,
  ('Services',
   'RoadAttributes',
   'egoInformationCompex',
   0,
   'speedlimit',
   'source')),
 (1,
  ('Services',
   'RoadAttributes',
   'egoInformationCompex',
   0,
   'speedlimit',
   'unit')),
 (5,
  ('Services',
   'RoadAttributes',
   'egoInformationCompex',
   0,
   'trafficOnline',
   'id')),
 (5,
  ('Services',
   'RoadAttributes',
   'egoInformationCompex',
   0,
   'trafficOnline',
   'distanceStdDev')),
 (5,
  ('Services',
   'RoadAttributes',
   'egoInformationCompex',
   0,
   'trafficOnline',
   'value')),
 (5,
  ('Services',
   'RoadAttributes',
   'egoInformationCompex',
   0,
   'trafficOnline',
   'indexAdditionalSignList',
   0)),
 (5,
  ('Services',
   'RoadAttributes',
   'egoInformationCompex',
   0,
   'trafficOnline',
   'indexAdditionalSignList',
   1)),
 (5,
  ('Services',
   'RoadAttributes',
   'egoInformationCompex',
   0,
   'trafficOnline',
   'indexAdditionalSignList',
   2)),
 (5,
  ('Services',
   'RoadAttributes',
   'egoInformationCompex',
   0,
   'trafficOnline',
   'source')),
 (1,
  ('Services',
   'RoadAttributes',
   'egoInformationCompex',
   0,
   'trafficOnline',
   'unit')),
 (5,
  ('Services',
   'RoadAttributes',
   'egoInformationCompex',
   0,
   'averageSpeed',
   'id')),
 (5,
  ('Services',
   'RoadAttributes',
   'egoInformationCompex',
   0,
   'averageSpeed',
   'distanceStdDev')),
 (5,
  ('Services',
   'RoadAttributes',
   'egoInformationCompex',
   0,
   'averageSpeed',
   'value')),
 (5,
  ('Services',
   'RoadAttributes',
   'egoInformationCompex',
   0,
   'averageSpeed',
   'indexAdditionalSignList',
   0)),
 (5,
  ('Services',
   'RoadAttributes',
   'egoInformationCompex',
   0,
   'averageSpeed',
   'indexAdditionalSignList',
   1)),
 (5,
  ('Services',
   'RoadAttributes',
   'egoInformationCompex',
   0,
   'averageSpeed',
   'indexAdditionalSignList',
   2)),
 (5,
  ('Services',
   'RoadAttributes',
   'egoInformationCompex',
   0,
   'averageSpeed',
   'source')),
 (1,
  ('Services',
   'RoadAttributes',
   'egoInformationCompex',
   0,
   'averageSpeed',
   'unit')),
 (1.0,
  ('Services', 'RoadAttributes', 'egoInformationCompex', 0, 'slope', 'slope')),
 (5,
  ('Services',
   'RoadAttributes',
   'egoInformationCompex',
   0,
   'slope',
   'distance')),
 (4,
  ('Services', 'RoadAttributes', 'egoInformationCompex', 0, 'messageCounter'))]
```

Update:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(list(fla_tu(data)))
df = pd.concat([df[0], df[1].apply(pd.Series)], axis=1, ignore_index=True)
df[df.columns[-1]] = df[df.columns[-1]].astype('Int64')
results = []
for name, group in df.groupby(df.columns[1:-2].to_list(), dropna=False):
    results.append([])
    for name2, group2 in group.groupby(group.columns[-2], dropna=False):
        results[-1].append([name2, group2[0].to_list()])
        if pd.isna(name2):
            for col in reversed(group2.columns.to_list()):
                if not pd.isna(fc:=(group2[col].iloc[0])):
                    results[-1][0][0] = fc
                    break
        if len(results[-1][-1][-1])==1:
            results[-1][-1][-1]=results[-1][-1][-1][0]


[[['distanceStdDev', 5.0],
  ['id', 5.0],
  ['indexAdditionalSignList', [5.0, 5.0, 5.0]],
  ['source', 5.0],
  ['unit', 1.0],
  ['value', 5.0]],
 [['messageCounter', 4.0]],
 [['distance', 5.0], ['slope', 1.0]],
 [['distanceStdDev', 5.0],
  ['id', 5.0],
  ['indexAdditionalSignList', [5.0, 5.0, 5.0]],
  ['source', 5.0],
  ['unit', 1.0],
  ['value', 5.0]],
 [['distanceStdDev', 5.0],
  ['id', 5.0],
  ['indexAdditionalSignList', [5.0, 5.0, 5.0]],
  ['source', 5.0],
  ['unit', 1.0],
  ['value', 5.0]]]
```

Edit 2:

If you want the list to be flat, take out     results.append([])
and adjust the indices.
It even might be that

```
df = pd.DataFrame(list(fla_tu(data)))
df = pd.concat([df[0], df[1].apply(pd.Series)], axis=1, ignore_index=True)
```

is exactly what you want.

```
print(df.to_string())
      0         1               2                     3  4               5                        6    7
0   5.0  Services  RoadAttributes  egoInformationCompex  0      speedlimit                       id  NaN
1   5.0  Services  RoadAttributes  egoInformationCompex  0      speedlimit           distanceStdDev  NaN
2   5.0  Services  RoadAttributes  egoInformationCompex  0      speedlimit                    value  NaN
3   5.0  Services  RoadAttributes  egoInformationCompex  0      speedlimit  indexAdditionalSignList  0.0
4   5.0  Services  RoadAttributes  egoInformationCompex  0      speedlimit  indexAdditionalSignList  1.0
5   5.0  Services  RoadAttributes  egoInformationCompex  0      speedlimit  indexAdditionalSignList  2.0
6   5.0  Services  RoadAttributes  egoInformationCompex  0      speedlimit                   source  NaN
7   1.0  Services  RoadAttributes  egoInformationCompex  0      speedlimit                     unit  NaN
8   5.0  Services  RoadAttributes  egoInformationCompex  0   trafficOnline                       id  NaN
9   5.0  Services  RoadAttributes  egoInformationCompex  0   trafficOnline           distanceStdDev  NaN
10  5.0  Services  RoadAttributes  egoInformationCompex  0   trafficOnline                    value  NaN
11  5.0  Services  RoadAttributes  egoInformationCompex  0   trafficOnline  indexAdditionalSignList  0.0
12  5.0  Services  RoadAttributes  egoInformationCompex  0   trafficOnline  indexAdditionalSignList  1.0
13  5.0  Services  RoadAttributes  egoInformationCompex  0   trafficOnline  indexAdditionalSignList  2.0
14  5.0  Services  RoadAttributes  egoInformationCompex  0   trafficOnline                   source  NaN
15  1.0  Services  RoadAttributes  egoInformationCompex  0   trafficOnline                     unit  NaN
16  5.0  Services  RoadAttributes  egoInformationCompex  0    averageSpeed                       id  NaN
17  5.0  Services  RoadAttributes  egoInformationCompex  0    averageSpeed           distanceStdDev  NaN
18  5.0  Services  RoadAttributes  egoInformationCompex  0    averageSpeed                    value  NaN
19  5.0  Services  RoadAttributes  egoInformationCompex  0    averageSpeed  indexAdditionalSignList  0.0
20  5.0  Services  RoadAttributes  egoInformationCompex  0    averageSpeed  indexAdditionalSignList  1.0
21  5.0  Services  RoadAttributes  egoInformationCompex  0    averageSpeed  indexAdditionalSignList  2.0
22  5.0  Services  RoadAttributes  egoInformationCompex  0    averageSpeed                   source  NaN
23  1.0  Services  RoadAttributes  egoInformationCompex  0    averageSpeed                     unit  NaN
24  1.0  Services  RoadAttributes  egoInformationCompex  0           slope                    slope  NaN
25  5.0  Services  RoadAttributes  egoInformationCompex  0           slope                 distance  NaN
26  4.0  Services  RoadAttributes  egoInformationCompex  0  messageCounter                      NaN  NaN
```

Comment: Thanks alot Hans..It worked as expected..only modification expected is list exist in dict  `indexAdditionalSignList": [ 5, 5, 5],`   It is giving one element at a time.. I want whole list like ..`['RoadAttributes', 'egoInformationCompex', 'speedlimit', 'indexAdditionalSignList', '5,5,5'] `..awaiting for your response.

Comment: I have just updated the post :)

Comment: Thanks again Hans..I just need an data in this format... all parameters inside single sublist instead of tuples  `['RoadAttributes', 'egoInformation', 'roundabout', 'id', 5]` and listdata like indexAdditionalSignList in the form of `['RoadAttributes', 'egoInformationCompex', 'speedlimit', 'indexAdditionalSignList', '5,5,5']` instead of three iterations..  so final output data should look like...in form of list of lists e.g. `[['RoadAttributes', 'egoInformationCompex', 'speedlimit', 'value', 5], ['RoadAttributes', 'egoInformationCompex', 'speedlimit', 'indexAdditionalSignList', '5,5,5']]`

Comment: Take the pandas DataFrame in my last edit and write down exactly how the output data of the WHOLE (not only a few lines) DataFrame should be look like.